# Image of exact sequence still exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, exact-sequence

I am reading Voisin's book *Hodge theorem and complex algebraic geometry II* and get stuck at this point. It the proof of Thm 3.22, on page 86. The setting is as follows. (I try to use the same notation)

Let $U'\to W$ be a fiber bundle, $F$ be a fiber (corresponding to $\Delta-\Delta\cap \mathcal Y$ in the book). Then we have a long exact sequence on the homotopy groups:

$$\ldots \pi_2(W) \to \pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(U') \to \pi_1(W) \to \pi_0(F) \to\ldots$$

And in our case $F$ is connected, hence we get

$$\ldots \pi_2(W) \to \pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(U') \to \pi_1(W) \to 1$$

There is another map $p$ (corresponding to $pr_1$ in the book) which is defind on $U'$. By restriction $p$ can be defined on $F$. Since $W$ can be identified with some section $W'$, $p$ also defined on $W$. Therefore we can apply $p_*$ to the sequence, get

$$\ldots p_* \pi_2(W) \to p_*\pi_1(F) \to p_*\pi_1(U') \to p_*\pi_1(W) \to 1$$

My question is

> Is this sequence still exact?

Form the contents it seems this is true. (It claims $p_*\pi_1(F) \to p_*\pi_1(U')$ is an isomorphism - in our case $p_* \pi_2(W)$ and $p_*\pi_1(W)$ are trivial) But I don't know why?

Comment: In what sense do you apply $p_*$ to a sequence of groups?

Comment: @Sasha Means the image of  $p_*=\pi_i(p)$.